# Rename Entity Framework T4 Template Generated Class Names?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have a database with a very large number of tables which unfortunately have been named with no standard convention whatsoever:

- TableName
- anotherTableName
- YETANOTHERTABLENAME
- Garbage_Table

I am using Entity Framework with the standard T4 Code Generation template to create the POCO classes in C#

Is there a best practice I can follow which lets me incorporate my own convention to name these tables in the C# app without having to touch anything in SQL? The auto-generated classes look like:

- TableNames.cs
- anotherTableNames.cs
- YETANOTHERTABLENAMEs.cs
- Garbage_Tables.cs

I would like to have some sort of a wrapper:

- CleanTableName => TableName
- CleanAnotherTableName => anotherTableName
- CleanYetAnotherTableName => YETANOTHERTABLENAME
- CleanGarbageTable => Garbage_Table

One approach would be to just create wrapper classes?.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If you go to your edmx file you can click on each of the entities and rename them in there (Entity Set Name & Name in the properties window). Then if your regenerate the classes created by the T4 template your classes will have the new names.

Comment: Thanks - will try this out - will I lose my renamed mapping of say 100+ tables if there are ongoing schema changes from new development in the database a week later and I 'refresh' the EF diagram to get the latest version of the schema?

Comment: No, not if you use refresh the model - but if you delete and re-add anything then your changes will be lost. If you make some schema changes and then refresh model you may have to update some of the mapping information - normally only if you rename the tables or columns.

Comment: @MattWhetton i doubt thats correct. I use Update/Refresh model instead of deleting and re creating the model and even then all my custom changes to the class are lost.

Comment: @WAQ that shouldn't be happening and in the projects that I've used it, refreshing the model does not lose changes.