# Can the naming convention used by Entity Framework 6.0 (Database first) be changed?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm totally new to Entity Framework. I have a very large application that used another framework where all properties and entities followed CamelCase naming. It seems my build with Entity Framework 6.0 is constructing the names as all lowercase.

I dread the hours/days it will take to change all the names to lowercase.

What is the best way to deal with this in a Database first scenario?

Much thanks for any suggestions.

(I'm using visual studio 2015, C#, Entity Framework 6.0, Npgsql 3.0.5, PostgreSQL 9.5)

Comment: You can change the default conventions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.conventionsconfiguration(v=vs.113).aspx and a list of conventions here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @Jasen  An example would be wonderful. Thanks.

Comment: @Jasen  I am quickly coming to the conclusion that it would be easier to change the T4 template used for code generation. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't offer more guidance as I don't use T4 templates. Maybe this answer can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505088/entity-framework-capitalizing-first-property-name-letter. There is another suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441170/rename-entity-framework-t4-template-generated-class-names.